# Using Chacha20 with a NULL nonce

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, chacha20

I am new to ChaCha20. From the RFC --

The inputs to ChaCha20 are:

o  A 256-bit key, treated as a concatenation of eight 32-bit little-
      endian integers.

o  A 96-bit nonce, treated as a concatenation of three 32-bit little-
      endian integers.

o  A 32-bit block count parameter, treated as a 32-bit little-endian
      integer.

Now the counter is not provided as an input option. They implement the counter underneath the hood. For the sake of this question, let's assume the counter is implemented properly.

Now if I use a NULL nonce, the counter is still used. Will it be ok?

Is the max number of messages that can be encrypted this way before the key must be changed 2^32?   or is it the max number of bytes?

Comment: You can see a better solution here [How to generate a nonce for ChaCha20 Poly1305?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77982/18298)

Answer (score 1):

A nonce doesn't have to be secret or unpredictable; it just can't be reused. It's perfectly fine to use an all-zero nonce **one time** with a given key. You just have to make sure you never reuse it, just as with any other nonce value you'd use. To be clear, this means a maximum of **one** message.

Comment: @SFlow Block level

Answer (score 1):

Another answer has the rule so how about some intuition:

ChaCha permutes a block of data into an unpredictable block of data and XORs it with your plaintext.  Because XOR is reversible, the same unpredictable block of data will return the ciphertext back to plaintext.

If two pieces of plaintext are the same and are xor-ed against the same bytes of unpredictable block, they come out to the same ciphertext value.  On a large enough scale an attacker would be able to see "oh that pattern appears several times, that must mean they are sending predictable text."  This is where a block count comes in.  The block count is mixed into the block to give a different unpredictable block of data for every block of plaintext.

But without anything else, if the same bytes of plaintext happen at the same part of a given block, they would always encrypt the same way every time.  Again, an attacker might see this pattern.  So we introduce a nonce, a large random number that is introduced in to the block to make it random for every message (and by the power of block count, every block of every message).

So, an IV of all zeros is okay, but if two plaintexts are encrypted with the same IV (zero or otherwise) it may reveal patterns in the plaintext to attackers.  The hard and fast rule is the IV should be generated completely randomly and transmitted along with the ciphertext.